# How to backup a fresh ubuntu server without snapshot or backup feature from the provider?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, reset, vps

I already bought an Ubuntu VPS, but the provider's control panel only gives me features to start and stop the VPS. It doesn't provide a way to backup/restore, take snapshots, or reinstall the VPS, so I am afraid to install anything on it. Currently, the VPS is in its default/fresh state, so I want to ask: is it possible to backup this VPS and then restore it to a fresh state? If it is possible, can anyone tell me how to do that step by step?

Comment: I haven't run into any service provider that has VPS that doesn't have some way to reset the VPS. So I would first contact them about it, as that doesn't seem normal.

Comment: @TechLoom I contacted them; no VPS reset or backup. They advised me to be extra cautious to avoid issues with the VPS. The provider, acting as a middleman, offers limited features through their control panel: starting/stopping VPS, monitoring CPU, and configuring the firewall.

Comment: @harrymc So, do I only need to back up/copy the root and its subdirectories? How can I restore them safely? What about file/folder permissions? How about the packages I've already upgraded and removed? Will they all be error-free without conflicts if I just restore/paste the backup? I need a safe way, because if I broke it, i'm doomed.

Comment: So the provider has no means of getting a "fresh" VPS? Are you dealing with the actual VPS host, or  reseller of some sort? Either way, it seems as though your root issue is a provider that doesn't provide the sort of services you need for running something like this. Even with a backup you need a means supported by the provider/host of returning the backed up data to the machine. The supported means of doing that will have to be given you by the provider/host.